# Saving files to mobile with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, phonegap-plugins

> I'm having real trouble trying to save both persistent and temporary
>   files with PhoneGap, I've followed all the examples and tutorials I
>   can find with no success, I'm sure it's something I'm doing wrong but
>   can someone give me a few examples of how to us the cordovan file
>   plugin.   Thanks for your time!

Okay so my problem has now changed, I can finally save the file using

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function (fs) {

console.log('file system open: ' + fs.name);
fs.root.getFile("newPersistentFile.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false }, function (fileEntry) {

    console.log("fileEntry is file?" + fileEntry.isFile.toString());
    // fileEntry.name == 'someFile.txt'
    // fileEntry.fullPath == '/someFile.txt'
    writeFile(fileEntry, null);

}, onErrorCreateFile);

}, onErrorLoadFs);
```

but I can't see the file once it has been saved, I'm looking to store the in the files directory of the android app but can't figure out how to do so.

Comment: We need to see your code. What had you tried to do?

Comment: My problems changed and I added the code I'm using now. Thanks!